# how to do automated integration test for service that has no delete operation and reuse the same data everytime it runs in c#

Tags: c#, automation, mstest

I have a WCF service (Create, Retrieve and Update Operations only), this is a ESB service and is designed such that no validation is taking place for the data, meaning same data can be passed again and again or you can pass in blank data leaving one mandatory field.

I need to do the integration tests for all three operations using the same data every time it runs.

Retrieve and Update can be automated because i can retrieve the same data multiple times and update too.

But how can i automate the create operation? I can create same record every time it runs but the retrieve doesn't know which data to retrieve from database since it has multiple rows of same data and i don't want to fill the database with same record.

I know this looks stupid but, this is the reality. Any suggestions and helps really appreciated.

Note: I have normal MSTest

Comment: Could you put a new GUID in one of the non-key fields every time the test runs, then search through the records and find the record with that same GUID? This would allow you to uniquely identify the record that was inserted in the current test run.

Comment: that's what i am doing right now to test but, you see the problem is every time i create the record database get filled up with dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

To take care of your test data issue, you could utilize either the test cleanup attribute or the class cleanup attribute, which are methods that are called immediately after all tests within a given class or method have finished running, respectively.  You could just call a stored procedure/query inside of the cleanup method that deletes all of your test data.  Instead of a different GUID for each record, use some other ID that the cleanup SQL can use to identify dummy data...

```
[TestClass()]
public sealed class MyClassTest
{

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
        // This method is called after all of the test methods in this
        // test class have finished running...call a cleanup stored procedure
    } 


    [TestMethod()]
    public void MyMethodTest()
    {
        // This is where you perform your test
    }
}
```

Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: thanks i am well aware of this but i don't have access to Database which is XRM side i am writing test in ESB side as mentioned in description

Answer (score 0):

The `System Under Test` **must** have a predefined known state before the tests are starting and each test **must** return the System to that state after it finished.

This means that every time a test calls the `Create` ,or any other method, the record must be deleted from the database in the `Cleanup` method. The tests have to be independent.

I know the `Create` method may add records at many tables and it is hard to do. An easy(?) way to do this is to re-deploy the database in the `Initialize` method or to [take a snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190467%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of the db at the `Initialize` and return db to that snapshot at the `Cleanup`.

Comment: Ya i had a thought about this method, and it's feasible in smaller project but the size of the project i am working on right now is so huge that this options becomes not an option. There are millions of records that are mapped with hundreds of other databases. And even i believe i won't have permission to do that. but ya thanks for the suggestion appreciate that.